# Struggling to reset WPF DataGrid columns after user moves them

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've got a quite specific problem that has eluded me for a couple of days now and I'm really hoping someone with better skills than me in C# can help.

I have a database with journey data which includes the price and number of journeys made from and to destinations. I want to display this in a grid which merges the to/from destination effectively making a triangle like the below image (achieved without a hitch)

[image: DataGrid]

The problem I have is I want the user to be able to order the columns as they wish by drag and dropping. I would then obtain the new order (got this bit okay) but what I can't seem to do is get the columns to go back to their original display.Index order and update the table again. I've tried manually creating the columns and autoGenerating both to no avail I get a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException on line 83 of OriginAndDestinationView class saying "The DisplayIndex for the DataGridColumn with Header 'Nottingham' is out of range.  DisplayIndex must be greater than or equal to 0 and less than Columns.Count"

```
customerGridHolder.ItemsSource = customerGrid;
```

I've got a custom DataGrid:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using trentbarton_Analytics.Interfaces;

namespace trentbarton_Analytics.CustomViews
{
    public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
    {

        private OnColumnReorderFinishedListener mListener;
        private SortedDictionary<int, string> newOrder;
        int oldIndex = -1;
        int newIndex = -1;
        bool firstIteration = true;

        public CustomDataGrid() : base()
        {
            newOrder = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
        }

        public void setOnColumnReorderFinishedListener(OnColumnReorderFinishedListener l)
        {
            mListener = l;
        }

        private bool hasColumnOrderingEnded()
        {

            //Should return true if all the columns have unique displayIndexes

            HashSet<int> tempSet = new HashSet<int>();

            foreach(DataGridColumn column in this.Columns)
            { 

                if (!tempSet.Add(column.DisplayIndex)) return false;

            }

            return true;
        }

        protected override void OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged(DataGridColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged(e);           

            storeColumnMovedPositions(e.Column);

            if (hasColumnOrderingEnded())
            {

                //Column order is now set, on the first iteration we need to store the new order and move the columns back
                if (firstIteration)
                {
                    firstIteration = false;
                    newOrder.Clear();

                    foreach (DataGridColumn column in this.Columns)
                    {
                        newOrder.Add(column.DisplayIndex, column.Header.ToString());
                    }

                    int i = 0;

                    foreach(DataGridColumn column in this.Columns)
                    {
                        //Restore the order based on list position
                        column.DisplayIndex = i++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    //The process has completed for the second time after we have moved all the columns so we can now pass back the new postion
                    if (mListener != null)
                    {
                        mListener.OnReorderFinished(new List<string>(newOrder.Values));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void storeColumnMovedPositions(DataGridColumn column)
        {
            //The first time this is called we get the column that was moved with it's new display index save these so we can move it back later

            if (oldIndex == -1)
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (DataGridColumn c in this.Columns)
                {
                    if (c == column)
                    {
                        //store the original index based on the list position of the column
                        oldIndex = i;
                    }

                    i++;
                }
            }

            if (newIndex == -1)
            {
                //store the new position based on the updated displayIndex
                newIndex = column.DisplayIndex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my implemention of the CustomView/UI

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using trentbarton_Analytics.DataModels;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using trentbarton_Analytics.Interfaces;

namespace trentbarton_Analytics.CustomViews
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for OriginAndDestinationView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class OriginAndDestinationView : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl, OnColumnReorderFinishedListener
    {
        private OriginAndDestinationGraph mGraph;

        public OriginAndDestinationView(List<Transaction> transactions)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            createGraph(tempSplitter(transactions));
            customerGridHolder.setOnColumnReorderFinishedListener(this);
        }

        //This is just a temporary filter to filter out a single service
        private List<Transaction> tempSplitter(List<Transaction> transactions)
        {
            List<Transaction> newTransactions = new List<Transaction>();
            string selectedService = transactions[0].service;

            foreach (Transaction t in transactions)
            {
                if (t.service.Equals(selectedService))
                {
                    newTransactions.Add(t);
                }
            }

            return newTransactions;

        }

        private async void createGraph(List<Transaction> transactions)
        {

            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                mGraph = new OriginAndDestinationGraph(transactions);
                mGraph.convert();
            });

            showOutput(mGraph.getUnweightedCustomerValues(), mGraph.getUnweightedRevenueValues());
        }

        private void hideLoading()
        {
            progressScreen.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            gridViewHolder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void showLoading()
        {
            progressScreen.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            gridViewHolder.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        private void showOutput(DataView customerGrid, DataView revenueGrid)
        {

            if (!customerGridHolder.HasItems)
            {
                customerGridHolder.ItemsSource = customerGrid;
                revenueGridHolder.ItemsSource = revenueGrid;                
            }
            else
            {
                customerGridHolder.ItemsSource = customerGrid;
                revenueGridHolder.ItemsSource = revenueGrid;
                customerGridHolder.Items.Refresh();
                revenueGridHolder.Items.Refresh();                
            }

            int i = 0;            

            foreach (string stage in mGraph.getAllStages())
            {
                revenueGridHolder.Columns[i].Header = stage;
                customerGridHolder.Columns[i].Header = stage;                
                i++;
            }

            hideLoading();
        }

        private void LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                e.Row.Header = mGraph.getAllStages()[e.Row.GetIndex()];
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }            
        }

        private void MouseWheelOverGrid(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            gridViewHolder.ScrollToVerticalOffset(gridViewHolder.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
        }

        private void CustomerGridHolder_ColumnReordering(object sender, DataGridColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            /*if (autoRefreshing) return;

            //Get indexes
            int oldIndex = getOriginalIndex(e.Column.Header.ToString());

            int newIndex = e.Column.DisplayIndex;

            if (!ColumnHeaderSelected) return;

            ColumnHeaderSelected = false;                      

            bool movedRight = newIndex > oldIndex;

            SortedDictionary<int, string> newOrder = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();

            ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> columns = customerGridHolder.Columns;

            foreach(DataGridColumn column in columns)
            {
                if(column == e.Column)
                {
                    newOrder.Add(newIndex, column.Header.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    if (movedRight)
                    {
                        if (column.DisplayIndex <= newIndex)
                        {
                            //Add with index reduced by 1
                            newOrder.Add(column.DisplayIndex - 1, column.Header.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newOrder.Add(column.DisplayIndex, column.Header.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Moved Left
                        if (column.DisplayIndex < oldIndex)
                        {
                            //Add with index increased by 1
                            newOrder.Add(column.DisplayIndex + 1, column.Header.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newOrder.Add(column.DisplayIndex, column.Header.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (mGraph.hasOrderChanged(new List<string>(newOrder.Values)))
            {
                mGraph.updateOrder(new List<string>(newOrder.Values));
                showOutput(mGraph.getUnweightedCustomerValues(), mGraph.getUnweightedRevenueValues());
            }*/

            Console.WriteLine("Column reodering called for column " + e.Column.Header.ToString() + " moved to position " + e.Column.DisplayIndex);

        }

        public void OnReorderFinished(List<string> newOrder)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New Order Defined:");

            foreach(string s in newOrder)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            //Send the new order to the dataSource to produce a new table
            mGraph.updateOrder(newOrder);
            showOutput(mGraph.getUnweightedCustomerValues(), mGraph.getUnweightedRevenueValues());

        }
    }
}
```

The XAML for the above code

```
<UserControl x:Class="trentbarton_Analytics.CustomViews.OriginAndDestinationView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:trentbarton_Analytics.CustomViews"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Background="White"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid x:Name="progressScreen" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Label Content="Processing Content...." TextElement.FontFamily="{StaticResource MuseoSans100}" TextElement.FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-100,0,0"/>
            <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="50,0" Foreground="Orange" Background="White"/>
        </Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Visibility="Visible" x:Name="gridViewHolder" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="contentHolder">
                <Label Content="Customers" TextElement.FontFamily="MuseoSans100" TextElement.FontSize="20" Height="auto" Margin="5,10,0,10"/>
                <custom:CustomDataGrid x:Name="customerGridHolder" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" LoadingRow="LoadingRow" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" PreviewMouseWheel="MouseWheelOverGrid" ColumnDisplayIndexChanged="CustomerGridHolder_ColumnReordering"/>
                <Label Content="Revenue" TextElement.FontFamily="MuseoSans100" TextElement.FontSize="20" Height="auto" Margin="5,30,0,10"/>
                <custom:CustomDataGrid x:Name="revenueGridHolder"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" LoadingRow="LoadingRow" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" PreviewMouseWheel="MouseWheelOverGrid" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And finally, the convertor which creates the DataView

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;

namespace trentbarton_Analytics.DataModels
{
    public class OriginAndDestinationGraph
    {
        public bool isWeighted { get; set; }
        private List<string> allStages;
        private List<string> originalStages;
        private List<Transaction> mTransactions;
        private Dictionary<string, string> mOverrideNames;
        private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, OriginAndDestinationDataItem>> mGraph;

        public OriginAndDestinationGraph(List<Transaction> transactions)
        {
            mTransactions = transactions;
            mOverrideNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            allStages = new List<string>();
            originalStages = new List<string>();
            mGraph = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, OriginAndDestinationDataItem>>();

        }

        public List<string> getAllStages(){
            return allStages;
        }

        public void convert()
        {
            //When coverting we want to change the List of transactions into a Dictionary that is unweighted
            if (mTransactions == null)
            {
                //if the list of transactions is null then we can't do anything
                return;
            }

            HashSet<string> uniqueStages = new HashSet<string>();

            foreach (Transaction t in mTransactions)
            {
                //If we know of any override names we should do this here
                string fromStageName = convertStageName(t.fromStage);
                string toStageName = convertStageName(t.toStage);

                uniqueStages.Add(fromStageName);
                uniqueStages.Add(toStageName);

                OriginAndDestinationDataItem item = new OriginAndDestinationDataItem();
                item.addCustomers(t.customerTripCount);
                item.addRevenue(Double.Parse(t.price.ToString()));
                addToGraph(fromStageName, toStageName, item);
            }

            //Add the unique Set to a List so it can be re-ordered
            allStages.AddRange(uniqueStages);

            if(originalStages.Count == 0)
            {
                originalStages.AddRange(uniqueStages);
            }
        }

        public DataView getUnweightedCustomerValues()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            foreach (string s in allStages)
            {
                table.Columns.Add();
            }

            foreach (string s in allStages)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(table.NewRow());
            }

            DataView dataView = new DataView(table);

            int offset = 0;

            int row = 0;
            int column = 0;

            foreach (string origin in allStages)
            {
                column = 0;

                foreach (string destination in allStages)
                {

                    if (column < offset)
                    {
                        dataView[row][column++] = "";
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        //Now add all the column data
                        dataView[row][column++] = String.Format("{0:n0}", Math.Round(getCustomersFromGraph(origin, destination)));
                    }
                }

                offset++;
                row++;

            }

            return dataView;                   

        }


        public bool hasOrderChanged(List<string> newOrder)
        {

            for(int i = 0; i < newOrder.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!newOrder[i].Equals(allStages[i]))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;

        }

        public void updateOrder(List<string> newOrder)
        {
            this.allStages = newOrder;
        }

        public DataView getUnweightedRevenueValues()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            foreach (string s in allStages)
            {
                table.Columns.Add();
            }

            foreach (string s in allStages)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(table.NewRow());
            }

            DataView dataView = new DataView(table);

            int offset = 0;

            int row = 0;
            int column = 0;

            foreach (string origin in allStages)
            {
                column = 0;

                foreach (string destination in allStages)
                {

                    if (column < offset)
                    {
                        dataView[row][column++] = "";
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        //Now add all the column data
                        dataView[row][column++] = String.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"), "{0:C}", getRevenueFromGraph(origin, destination));
                    }
                }

                offset++;
                row++;

            }

            return dataView;            

        }



        private double getCustomersFromGraph(string origin, string destination)
        {
            double customers = 0;
            Dictionary<String, OriginAndDestinationDataItem> inner;
            OriginAndDestinationDataItem tempItem;

            if(mGraph.TryGetValue(origin, out inner))
            {
                if(inner.TryGetValue(destination, out tempItem))
                {
                    customers += tempItem.getCustomers();
                }

            }

            if (mGraph.TryGetValue(destination, out inner))
            {
                if (inner.TryGetValue(origin, out tempItem))
                {
                    customers += tempItem.getCustomers();
                }
            }


            return customers;

        }

        private double getRevenueFromGraph(string origin, string destination)
        {
            double revenue = 0;
            Dictionary<String, OriginAndDestinationDataItem> inner;
            OriginAndDestinationDataItem tempItem;

            if (mGraph.TryGetValue(origin, out inner))
            {
                if (inner.TryGetValue(destination, out tempItem))
                {
                    revenue += tempItem.getRevenue();
                }

            }

            if (mGraph.TryGetValue(destination, out inner))
            {
                if (inner.TryGetValue(origin, out tempItem))
                {
                    revenue += tempItem.getRevenue();
                }
            }


            return revenue;

        }

        public void addOverrideName(string originalName, string overrideName)
        {
            mOverrideNames.Add(originalName, overrideName);
            allStages.Remove(originalName);
            Dictionary<string, OriginAndDestinationDataItem> inner;

            foreach(string key in mGraph.Keys)
            {
                if(mGraph.TryGetValue(key, out inner))
                {
                    foreach(string key2 in inner.Keys)
                    {
                        OriginAndDestinationDataItem tempItem;

                        if(inner.TryGetValue(key2, out tempItem))
                        {
                            if (key.Equals(originalName) && key2.Equals(originalName))
                            {
                                //from and to destination need changing
                                this.addToGraph(overrideName, overrideName, tempItem);
                            }

                            if(key.Equals(originalName) && !key2.Equals(originalName))
                            {
                                //the from stage needs changing but the to stage is fine
                                this.addToGraph(overrideName, key2, tempItem);
                            }

                            if(!key.Equals(originalName) && key2.Equals(originalName))
                            {
                                //the to stage needs changing but the from stage is fine
                                this.addToGraph(key, overrideName, tempItem);
                            }
                        }                        
                    }
                }
            }


            //Now we swapped all the values delete the orignal's from the Graph
            mGraph.Remove(originalName);

            foreach (string key in mGraph.Keys)
            {
                if (mGraph.TryGetValue(key, out inner))
                {
                    inner.Remove(originalName);
                }
            }
        }


        private string convertStageName(string stage)
        {
            if (stage == null || stage.Equals(""))
            {
                return "unknown";
            }

            if (mOverrideNames == null)
            {
                return stage.ToLower();
            }

            string value;
            if (mOverrideNames.TryGetValue(stage, out value))
            {
                return value.ToLower();
            }
            else
            {
                return stage;
            }
        }

        private void addToGraph(string fromStage, string toStage, OriginAndDestinationDataItem item)
        {
            //This function creates the inital unweightedGraph

            Dictionary<string, OriginAndDestinationDataItem> internalDict;

            if (!mGraph.TryGetValue(fromStage, out internalDict))
            {
                internalDict = new Dictionary<string, OriginAndDestinationDataItem>();
                mGraph.Add(fromStage, internalDict);
            }

            OriginAndDestinationDataItem tempAmount;

            if (!internalDict.TryGetValue(toStage, out tempAmount))
            {
                internalDict.Add(toStage, item);
            }
            else
            {
                tempAmount.addCustomers(item.getCustomers());
                tempAmount.addRevenue(item.getRevenue());
            }
        }

        private void weightGraph()
        {
            weightFromStage();
            weightToStages();
        }

        private void weightToStages()
        {

        }

        private void weightFromStage()
        {
            Dictionary<string, OriginAndDestinationDataItem> fromUnknown;
            if (!mGraph.TryGetValue("unknown", out fromUnknown))
            {
                return;
            }

            double totalRevenueValueNotKnown = 0;
            double totalCustomerValueNotKnown = 0;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, OriginAndDestinationDataItem> entry in fromUnknown)
            {
                totalCustomerValueNotKnown += entry.Value.getCustomers();
                totalRevenueValueNotKnown += entry.Value.getRevenue();
            }

            //Now we have the amount remove it from the Dictionary
            mGraph.Remove("unknown");

            if (totalRevenueValueNotKnown <= 0 && totalCustomerValueNotKnown <= 0)
            {
                //There is no reason to try and balance things because the values are zero so ignore
                return;
            }

            Dictionary<string, double> weightsFromRevenue = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            Dictionary<string, double> weightsFromCustomers = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            double totalRevenue = 0;
            double totalCustomers = 0;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, OriginAndDestinationDataItem>> row in mGraph)
            {
                Dictionary<string, OriginAndDestinationDataItem> column = row.Value;

                double revenue = 0;
                double customers = 0;

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, OriginAndDestinationDataItem> cell in column)
                {
                    revenue += cell.Value.getRevenue();
                    totalRevenue += cell.Value.getRevenue();
                    customers += cell.Value.getCustomers();
                    totalCustomers += cell.Value.getCustomers();
                }

                //add the total row amount
                weightsFromRevenue.Add(row.Key, revenue);
                weightsFromCustomers.Add(row.Key, customers);
            }

            //We now have the amounts for every FromDestionation in weightsFrom Dictionary
            if (totalRevenue <= 0 && totalCustomers <= 0)
            {
                //If for some reason the weighting table contains 0 in amounts then we can't really do anything so return
                return;
            }

            if (totalCustomers > 0)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> entry in weightsFromCustomers)
                {
                    //Loop through each of the weights
                    //get the percentage weighed amount
                    double weightedAmount = (entry.Value / totalCustomers) * totalCustomerValueNotKnown;

                    OriginAndDestinationDataItem existingAmount;
                    Dictionary<string, OriginAndDestinationDataItem> inner;

                    if (mGraph.TryGetValue(entry.Key, out inner))
                    {
                        if (inner.TryGetValue("unknown", out existingAmount))
                        {
                            existingAmount.addCustomers(weightedAmount);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            OriginAndDestinationDataItem item = new OriginAndDestinationDataItem();
                            item.addCustomers(weightedAmount);                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (totalRevenue > 0)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> entry in weightsFromRevenue)
                {
                    //Loop through each of the weights
                    //get the percentage weighed amount
                    double weightedAmount = (entry.Value / totalRevenue) * totalRevenueValueNotKnown;

                    OriginAndDestinationDataItem existingAmount;
                    Dictionary<string, OriginAndDestinationDataItem> inner;

                    if (mGraph.TryGetValue(entry.Key, out inner))
                    {
                        if (inner.TryGetValue("unknown", out existingAmount))
                        {
                            existingAmount.addRevenue(weightedAmount);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            OriginAndDestinationDataItem item = new OriginAndDestinationDataItem();
                            item.addRevenue(weightedAmount);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Please excuse the code if it appears in a bit of a mess I'm trying to get this to work before I refactor it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to do a horrible hacky solution to this but it does work but if anyone comes across something better please do say.

In my custom data grid. I created a background thread which ended the hold the OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged had on my code and then after a small delay of 50ms I call the code to re-order the columns back to how they were and build the new Graph

```
protected override void OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged(DataGridColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ignoreReorder)
            {
                return;
            }

            base.OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged(e);           

            storeColumnMovedPositions(e.Column);

            if (hasColumnOrderingEnded())
            {

                newOrder.Clear();

                foreach (DataGridColumn column in this.Columns)
                {
                    newOrder.Add(column.DisplayIndex, column.Header.ToString());
                }

                if (mListener != null)
                {
                    new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                            mListener.OnReorderFinished(new List<string>(newOrder.Values));
                        }));                        
                    }).Start();
                }                
            }
        }
```